# Knockout.JS click binding passes null to handler function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an HTML button with the following binding:

```
<td><button data-bind="click: $root.goOrder">Order</button></td>
```

that is part of a table populated with a knockout.js ajax callback. This all works fine but when
I click the button and the **"$root.goOrder"** function is called as defined here:

```
self.goOrder = function(client) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(client));
  $.ajax({
    url: "api/GetClient",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(client.id),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(data) {
      if (data) {
        //Will redirect to order page from here
      }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(errorThrown);
    }
  });
};
```

The **alert(JSON.stringify(client))** line shows the **client** parameter to be **[]** or undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post par of code where you are binding current context? (i.e client)

Comment: I think you have a missing code in passing knockout js parameter, you should declare like this 
<td><button data-bind="click: $root.goOrder(clientdata)">Order</button></td>

Comment: What happens if you replace the `alert(JSON.stringify(client))` with `console.log(item)`?

Comment: @Renzoburo. Any luck?

Comment: Thank you so uch. I was under the impression that the object returned was empty but with examination and actually accessing the object properties without the stringify bit, I managed to get the values out. This is my first time posting here. How do I upvote your answer @Jose Luis?

Comment: @Renzoburo I'm glad to help, welcome to knockout.  :-)  In fact, the correct answer to your question was in this link:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html ( replace `JSON.stringify()` with `ko.toJSON()` ).